# Need help manually adding to a dictionary

Tags: c#

I am confused I am trying to manually add entries to a Dictionary but its throwing an error at the first comma. Any help is appreciated thank you.

```
        private Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> packData =
        new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
        {
            {
                "Test", //issue here
                {
                    "Test" , "Test"
                }
            };
        };
```

[image]

Comment: Hint, when posting, use different strings, not all "Test". Try new Dict `{{"Test", new Dictionary <string, string> {"test", "test"}}};`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to be explicit about the inner dictionary:

```
    new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>()
    {
        {
            "Test", 
            new Dictionary<string, string> 
            {
                "Test" , "Test"
            }
        };
    };
```

The rule to follow here is "imagine if the thing in the braces was replaced with a call to `Add`".  In your original code, we would have lowered this to:

```
    temp = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    temp.Add("Test", { "Test", "Test" });
```

Which is not legal code.  But

```
    temp = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    temp.Add("Test", new Dictionary<string, string>(){ "Test", "Test" });
```

is legal, and in turn corresponds to

```
    temp = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>>();
    temp2 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    temp2.Add("Test", "Test");
    temp.Add("Test", temp2);
```

I often find when I'm confused that it helps to "lower" the code into its more basic form to understand what's going on.

There are some situations in which the compiler is smarter about understanding the intended meaning of nested braces like in your original code, but unfortunately this is not one of them. See the specification for more details about what is and is not supported; you'll want to search for "object initializers" and "collection initializers".

Comment: Thank you very much upvoted, and will accept once 5 minutes passes.

Comment: @LevonRavel: You're welcome. If you find that you're using multi-level dictionaries like this a lot, you might consider building a custom collection type that has the semantics you want. Is what you're trying to do here make a dictionary that is effectively keyed off of a *pair* of strings?

Comment: Eric Lippert, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Action<Writer, Queue<NetHelper.Data>, Packet>>> this is essentially the dictionary I am creating.. Its a bit in depth I am using the CodeCompiler to create a class for networking in Unity3D. :)

Comment: @LevonRavel: Wow, that's quite the type! I would definitely suggest creating a type whose interface matches your needs, and then build that dictionary-of-dictionaries as an implementation detail.